# NullReferenceException: at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdateDefaultString

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

My PurchaseOrder business object contained

```
public int? ReceivedByStaffId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ReceivedByStaffId")]
public virtual Staff ReceivedBy { get; set; }
```

And I was using the Audit module.

My Controller was throwing the following error on objectSpace.CommitChanges();

```
System.Exception: SaveChanges: inner: 
 ex:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdateDefaultString(IEFCoreWeakReference objectForUpdate, EntityEntry entityEntry, Object key)
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdatePersistentData(List`1 weakReferences)
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataContainer.AttachAuditData(DbContext dbContext)
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataContainer.SaveAuditData(DbContext dbContext)
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditTrailService.AuditedDbContext_SavedChanges(Object sender, SavedChangesEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at MyApp2.Module.BusinessObjects.MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges() in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Module\BusinessObjects\MyAppDbContext.cs:line 462 
  stacktrace:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at MyApp2.Module.BusinessObjects.MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges() in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Module\BusinessObjects\MyAppDbContext.cs:line 462
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit()
   at DevExpress.EntityFrameworkCore.Security.SecuredEFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.BaseObjectSpace.CommitChanges()
   at MyApp2.Module.Win.Features.PurchFeature.POStateViewController.actPurchStateMenu_Execute(Object sender, SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs args) in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Module.Win\Features\PurchFeature\POStateViewController.cs:line 207
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBase.ExecuteCore(Delegate handler, ActionBaseEventArgs eventArgs)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.SingleChoiceAction.DoExecute(ChoiceActionItem selectedItem)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.Binding.SingleChoiceActionBinding.ActionControl_Execute(Object sender, SingleChoiceActionControlExecuteEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem.OnClick(BarItemLink link)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkClick()
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.OnLinkAction(BarLinkAction action, Object actionArgs)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarSelectionInfo.UnPressLink(BarItemLink link)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomLinksControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.Start()
   at MyApp2.Win.Program.Main() in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Win\Program.cs:line 112 
   at MyApp2.Module.BusinessObjects.MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges() in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Module\BusinessObjects\MyAppDbContext.cs:line 468
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit()
   at DevExpress.EntityFrameworkCore.Security.SecuredEFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.BaseObjectSpace.CommitChanges()
   at MyApp2.Module.Win.Features.PurchFeature.POStateViewController.actPurchStateMenu_Execute(Object sender, SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs args) in D:\dev\MyApp2\MyApp2.Module.Win\Features\PurchFeature\POStateViewController.cs:line 207
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Foreign Key is nullable the navigation property also needs to be nullable

```
   public int? ReceivedByStaffId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ReceivedByStaffId")]
   public virtual Staff? ReceivedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is the second time I spent hours on this, so hopefully this post will save me next time.